# Predefined C# types, how can they behave this way?

Tags: c#, .net

i am just wondering about the way C# predefined types behave.

Considering this example:

```
int x= 5;
x.ToString();
```

it is known that int type is value type but ints do inherit form base object class (Like any Class in C#), so how can ints be value type-classes ? is there any way to make a user-defined class like this (value type not reference type)?

Comment: Any class can have static methods. It's just that a static class can have static methods *only*.

Comment: 1. Yes, you can create your own `struct`. 2. See `static` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating user-defined value types in C#, create `struct` definitions as shown:

```
public struct MyDesiredValueType
{
    public int MyDesiredProperty
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MyDesiredValueType(int myDesiredPropertyValue)
    {
        this.MyDesiredProperty = myDesiredPropertyValue;
    }
}
```

To make use of it,

```
public class TestMyDesiredValueType
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyDesiredValueType vt = new MyDesiredValueType(20);
        System.Console.WriteLine(vt.MyDesiredProperty);
    }
}
```

For more details regarding how to use structs, please refer the following:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taef578.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Value types are defined using struct, eg

```
public struct Int32
```

Non static classes can have static methods on them, eg

```
public class string
{
    public static string Format(....
}
```